# Sorting a LinkedList in ascending order

Tags: java, sorting, linked-list, nodes

What's the easiest way to sort a linked list? I have a list of nodes which each have 2 properties, one int and one string. How should I go about sorting the list in ascending integer order?

Comment: You can just call `Collections#sort`. But note that the runtime will be very suboptimal when using `LinkedList`. Consider adding everything to a better data-structure and then sorting that. Create a linked-list from it afterwards. Alternatively just add all elements to a `PriorityQueue` and then `pull` all elements from it (it automatically sorts), adding them to a new `LinkedList`.

Comment: Questions asking for *homework help* **must** include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it ([help], [ask]).

Comment: If you have implemented the list yourself,the simplest way is 1) put nodes into array, 2) use Arrays::sort to sort the nodes, 3) rebuild the list from the sorted nodes.

Comment: Linked list has a slow random-access performance. Merge sort is preferred over other `O(n log n)` sorting algorithms for this reason.

Comment: @Zabuza - how is collections#sort implemented for linked lists? Using a bottom up merge sort with a small (26 to 32) array of references to nodes is reasonably fast. Somewhat slower is top down merge sort for linked lists which repeatedly scans sub-lists in order to split them. The bottom up merge sort is all sequential access.

Answer (score 1):

### Sort

You could just call `Collection#sort` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-)). But note that the runtime will be very suboptimal due to `LinkedList` not providing `RandomAccess`.

It will probably be better to add everything into a better suited data-structure like `ArrayList`, sorting that and afterwards rebuilding a `LinkedList`:

```
LinkedList<X> input = ...

ArrayList<X> list = new ArrayList<>(input);
Collections.sort(list);

input = new LinkedList<>(list);
```

Alternatively you could add everything into a `PriorityQueue` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html)) which provides a sorted `poll` operation:

```
LinkedList<X> input = ...

PriorityQueue<X> queue = new PriorityQueue(input);
input = new LinkedList<>();
while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
    input.add(queue.poll());
}
```

If your `LinkedList` doesn't extend `Collection` you can't call handy constructors like `new ArrayList<>(input)`. In that case you need to manually add all elements to the other list.

---

### Comparator

If you want to sort you need to define some **order**. You have several options here.

You can make your `Node` objects implement `Comparable` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html?is-external=true)). Then you need to define a `compareTo` method which defines the relation between two objects. The provided methods will use this **natural order** then.

Alternatively you can create a `Comparator` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)) which also defines a `compare` method. The provided methods all take a `Comparator` as optional argument, like:

```
Collections.sort(list, comp);
// or
PriorityQueue<X> queue = new PriorityQueue(input, comp);
```

The method will then probably look like:

```
@Override
public int compare(Node first, Node second) {
    return Integers.compare(first.getIntProperty(), second.getIntProperty());
}
```

With Java 8 you can create such a `Comparator` very compact:

```
Comparator<Node> comp = Comparator.comparing(Node::getIntProperty);
```